# Codeigniter and boilerplate integration - jQuery undefined issue

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, html5boilerplate

I have integrated boiler plate with Codeigniter. I am using codeigniter templates. When I am calling any jQuery inline functions in a page it says '$ is not defined' in the console. So I copied the jquery code and put it in the main.js file and it worked. However when I am including any script file in this page which is dependent on the jquery plugin, it shows me the same jquery undefined error. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@WillemLabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579996/willemlabu) is correct, you can't use jQuery before it is defined. You must place your scripts that use jQuery after jQuery is included in the page.

The Boilerplate puts the scripts in the footer because typical Applications would run their javascript from external scripts in the footer.

The solution is

1. Put jQuery in the head; or
2. Put jQuery in the foot and attach inline scripts to an object that is run after the jQuery include.

You might do this like this:

**head.php**

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
<!-- define a global object to attach your scripts to -->
<script type="text/javascript">APP_READY = { callbacks: []};</script>
</head>
```

**yourView.php**

```
<!-- add your inline scripts inside the APP_READY namespace -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// MODULE
APP_READY.callbacks.push(function() {

  alert('simple example of APP_READY Callback');

});
</script>
```

**anotherView.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// MODULE
APP_READY.callbacks.push(function() {

  var exampleModule = [];

  exampleModule.init = function() {
    alert('modular example of APP_READY Callback');
  };

  exampleModule.init();

});
</script>
```

**foot.php**

```
<!-- include jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- execute your Object -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  // Initialise the callbacks
  //
  for (var i =0; i<APP_READY.callbacks.length; i++ ) {
    var callback = APP_READY.callbacks[i];

    if(callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback();
    }
  }

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs sequentially, meaning that you need to include jQuery before you try and use it.

Make sure jQuery is included before (above) any other code that tries to use `$()` or `jQuery()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I know that it runs sequentially. But if you will have a look at the HTML5 Boiler plate design, It loads all the javascript files and the end. In this case what to do??

Comment: Same thing still applies, the HTML5BP just follows best practise of loading scripts after the DOM & CSS. The point is, *any* JavaScript that requires jQuery needs to be included after jQuery has been loaded, because up until then, the `$` and `jQuery` variables will be `undefined`.

Comment: I agree. But I don't want to overload my header/footer with all external JavaScript plugin calls instead I would want to include external plugins in the page itself where ever necessary. Is there any way I can do this??

Comment: Check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org), or just put all your plugins in the HTML5BP plugins.js file, and cache it heavily.